# Generate FPDF Table From Database Based on Search Button

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I have a homework where I need to call a table from the **database**, display it on the webpage and have a button that will print a ***pdf*** of it. I also have a **search button** on my page where I can search a certain date and all the datas from the **db** that have that *"certain date"* will be displayed.

My question is, I wonder if I can print all that datas that have that *"certain date"* into ***pdf***? I am having a hard time thinking on how to do this since that only way I do to call the data from the database into **fpdf** is using the `SELECT * FROM table` code, which is wrong because all the table's data are being printed not the datas that have the *"certain date"* that I want.

I hope you guys can help me figure this out. Thank you so much.

Below is how my webpage looks like. 
[image]

You can see that theres a `Sort button` in which the user can sort the datas based on the date. And the `Generate PDF button` where, the filtered datas that the user entered on the `Sort button` will be printed into PDF.

Comment: Hint: that's when `WHERE` clauses are generally used to the filter the table data. Whatever the column name that stores the date would be the filter to get only the dates matches being searched.

Comment: @PaulT. yup I also think of that but my problem is the search bar and the pdf codes are in different file so I don't really know how to call the variables.

Comment: I don't know your setup, but generally, for PDF things that I've worked with, the PDF library is simply a file that is `include`d, or `require`d into the file that is being used to create the PDF _after_ retrieving the data. Of course, there are likely other ways, but if this is not the same for you, then we'd need more details.

Comment: @PaulT. what I mean with different file is, the **search bar** is located inside the `index.php` file while my**pdf codes** on which I coded my pdf design and called the table from _database_ is located inside the `printpdf.php`. I hope my explanation helps.

Comment: Then in that case it "sounds like" the index.php file has a form for the search bar, and then the form's action would submit the search to printpdf.php?  Then use the form variables within printpdf.php like any other typical submit handling.

Comment: @PaulT. It wont directly be printed into pdf as soon as the search button is clicked. The filtered datas will be displayed on the webpage first. And then theres a button that says **_Generate PDF_** and when the user clicked that button then that is the time where the filtered datas will be printed into the pdf.

Comment: This is exactly why [m.v.c.e](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)'s are important. Too much back and forth. (some might say the original question is too-broad) Well, the handling is entirely up to you. The Generate PDF button can still have a form of its own, but would need hidden inputs that have the same values (sort and whatever else) that were used to match the search. When generate is clicked, then those are passed on the printpdf.php script to process. Another way could potentially use an AJAX solution, but this _could_ be more involved if you've not yet had much experience using AJAX.